# Cannot resolve symbol 'firebase', even with updated gradle files

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting an error that says ***Can not resolve symbol 'firebase'***

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
        }
    });
}
```

I've also updated my ***.gradle files*** to have the latest dependencies..

app level:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

project level:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It looks like you pasted JavaScript code into Java file.  That's not gonna work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you are using the javascript code and the [web implementation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) in a java class and it can't work.

In your case you have to use the [Android implementation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users), in java or kotlin.

Comment: That's actually not the equivalent code to the pasted JS.

Comment: @DougStevenson you are right, may be he can attach an AuthStateListener, but here the problem is not "what is the best way to get the current user" but just the use of another language in a wrong context.

Comment: Then just say that, and don't give misleading advice.  (Also, the OP tagged as java, not kotlin.)

Comment: @DougStevenson To avoid any misleading advice I've just removed the code since it is not important the implementation but only the language used. In any case I'am not sure that I can link directly the java or kotlin implementation instead of the chapter link of manage-users in the documentation.